# BlockUI scrolls to top

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the JQuery BlockUI plugin:

```
function block(msg) {
    $.blockUI({
        message: msg,
        css: {
            border: 'none',
            padding: '15px',
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
            opacity: .8,
            color: '#fff'
        }
    });
}

function unblock() {
    $.unblockUI();
}
```

The problem I am facing is, as soon as I call it, it scrolls my page to the top. This is not good.

Here is the generated html:

[image]

Is there anything I could modify so that it does not touch the pageoffset / scrolling? Is there anything I could do to preserve it or anything?

Thanks

called here:

```
function callBump(realid) {

    block('Bumping...');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CalendarServices.aspx/Bump",
        data: 'id=' + realid,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
            unblock();
        }
,
        error: function () {
            unblock();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How are you "calling" it? (I can't see your screenshot, imgur is blocked for me.)

Comment: I have added the call.

Comment: The block is what affects the scroll though... it is affected immediately.

Comment: Thanks -- and how is `callBump()` initiated? Is if from an anchor tag click by chance?

Comment: It is from clicking an <a> tag

Comment: In your code that binds the click handler (i.e. `$('.something').click(function(e) { /* do stuff */ });`, make sure you have an `e.preventDefault()` after "do stuff".

Comment: There is no e

     $(btnBump).off('click');
                            $(btnBump).on('click', function () {
                                callBump(event.realid);
                            })

Comment: See the last updates to my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the jump to the top is caused by having something like this:

```
<a href="#" id="do_bump">Bump!</a>
```

Whatever click event you have bound to that link is executing but then it continues to attempt to navigate to "#" which is causing the jump.

It can be fixed by capturing the event parameter (add the `e` to your click event handler) and calling `preventDefault()` on it. This prevents the default link click behavior from occurring, which is to navigate to the `href` attribute value.

Given your comments, you have this:

```
$(btnBump).off('click'); 
$(btnBump).on('click', function () { 
    callBump(event.realid); 
});
```

Where is `event` coming from? Is this `window.event`? Assuming jQuery might mangle your event, try this (you just have to add the event parameter `e`):

```
$(btnBump).on('click', function(e) {
    callBump(event.realid);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```